# Sqlite: how do I fix pimary key autoincrement?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have a TOTALCOUNT table with a PK _id column named COUNTID and an integer column named CARDNUM.  I do an insert on CARDNUM so the PK will autoincrement.  But when I do LogCat output in Android Studio it shows _id = 1 for the first insert and then _id =1 for the second insert.  I thought the second insert should show _id =2.

DBContract file:

```
...
public static final String TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT = "totalcount";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNTID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM = "cardnum";
    }
}

A second table, not shown is called USERINPUTS.
```

DBHelper file:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Set up the Column headings for USERINPUTS and TOTALCOUNT Tables.
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CARDNUM);
}

private static final String SQL_CREATE_CARDNUM =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +
             "(" + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COUNTID +
                   " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                   DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
                   " INTEGER" + ")";

public void insertIntoTableTOTALCOUNT() {

    int cardnum = 0;
    // Get a reference to a writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM,cardnum);
    db.insert(DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT,null,cv);

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    // Close the database.
    if(db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}


Log.d("TAG", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I tried to create a table in SQLite (Firefox client) with below query. it gave me an error

```
create table my_table (_id integer primary key not null autoincrement,name varchar(20))
```

try this

```
create table my_table (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name varchar(20))
```

and you do not need to use `not null` for `PK with Auto Increment` as it never be null.

Comment: Ok will remove and re-try.

Comment: Unfortunately same result.

Comment: not only remove.. un-install the app and run again. as table needs to deleted.

Comment: same result because.. `SQLiteHelper` `onCreate` is called only once when you first run your app.. so uninstall and try again.

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear.  I uninstalled app and then incremented the database version in SQLiteOpenHelper so it would create a new table.

Comment: the final solution will be to check your database structure. open Android Device Monitor -> data -> data- > your package -> database -> copy the database to computer and check structure.

Comment: Ok.  Haven't used Device Monitor...do you know of any links to tutorials?  I am on a Windows 10 PC.  Do I need viewer program to open and see structure?

Comment: Dear downvoter :) hope you checked (executed) queries and downvoted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111816/discussion-between-skadoosh-and-ajw).